# Поиск тега в xml документе Python

Tags: xml, парсер, python-2.x, xmlparser, xpath

В **Python 2.7** есть библиотека **xml**, с помощью которой я делаю парсинг файла и поиск тегов в нём. По умолчанию, данная либа поддерживает урезанный функционал для **XPath**. Отсюда возникает вопрос: как найти тег, если я не знаю полного значения его атрибута, но при этом нельзя пользоваться встроенной функцией XPath "contains".

Есть xml:

```
<root>
    <item class="'$(param)'=='var'">
        ...
    </item>
    <item class="'$(param)'=='func'">
        ...
    </item>
    <item class="'$(param)'=='var_1'">
        ...
    </item>
</root>
```

Хочется использовать такой путь для поиска (найти все тэги "item", которые содержат в значении атрибута "class" подстроку "var"):

```
xpath = "/item[contains(@class, 'var')]"
```

Но питон возвращает ошибку, что используется неверный предикат. Подскажите, как найти требуемый элемент?

Comment: Проблема решилась использованием библиотеки **lxml** вместо xml.